# How do I create a user-defined redirect in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, subdomain

I have created a model called LandingPage, and the current route is something like:

```
www.domain.com/landing_pages/1
```

Or something like that.  I will have several of these, so landing_page where id = 1...n.

However, when someone creates the landing page, I would like them to be able to define an attribute for the model, such as "superbowl" to redirect to landing_page/1, "nice" to landing_page/2, etc.

This would allow the user to define the landing page as:

```
subdomian.domain.com/superbowl
```

which would resolve to

```
www.domain.com/landing_pages/1/
```

How do I do that?  Each landing_page has an attribute 'shortname' which ties to its specific landing_page.

I am on Rails 2.3.8.  My hunch is in the routes to loop through the available shortnames, but not sure.

```
 8   def show
  9     
 10     @landing_page = LandingPage.where(:name => params[:name]).first
 11     redirect_to landing_page_path(@landing_page)
 12     
 13     #@landing_page = LandingPage.find(params[:id])
 14     @redcloth_landing_page = RedCloth.new(@landing_page.message).to_html
 15     form = "<div id='form'>" << @landing_page.form << "</div>"
 16     
 17     @redcloth_landing_page.gsub!("{Form}",form)
 18     
 19     render :layout => false
 20   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your comments into account, you need a RedirectsController, and in your routes.rb file, you would have:

```
map.connect '/:name', :controller => 'redirects', :action => 'show'
```

You need to make sure that this route comes after your resource routes.  In your RedirectsController, the show method would be something like:

```
def show
  @landing_page = LandingPage.first(:conditions => {:name => params[:name]})
  redirect_to @landing_page
end
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve at www.domain.com/landing_pages/1/, but using your code as an example, you should have the following in your LandingPagesController show action:

```
def show

  @landing_page = LandingPage.find(params[:id])
  @redcloth_landing_page = RedCloth.new(@landing_page.message).to_html
  form = "<div id='form'>" << @landing_page.form << "</div>"

  @redcloth_landing_page.gsub!("{Form}",form)

  render :layout => false
end
```

However, this solution is not as good as before because, unless I am missing it, I do not know that you can constrain a route to a subdomain in 2.3.8.  Without constraining to subdomains, you would have to make sure your users did not use one of your controllers' names as a landing page word, adding complexity to your program.

There is a plugin, called subdomain-fu, which should allow you to restrict your routes to a subdomain.  The project is located at https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu.  I hope this helps, if not let me know.

Comment: To add to @Sean, you can use something like https://github.com/slainer68/acts_as_slug to create url slugs

Comment: I don't have a path parameter, but presumablye I could use landing_page_url(@landing_page)?

Comment: @Prateekdayal -- acts_as_slug looks interesting, is the slug automatically relative to the domain, even if, say, it is nested such as domian.com/user/1/landing_page/3 ?  If so, how do i set that up?

Comment: @sean, thanks, I haven't used match before...this seems interesting and sounds like the way to do it...I will check it out...

Comment: That should work, assuming that you have landing_pages as a resource.  Also, I just realized that you may want to restrict the route to a subdomain, which I have added to my edit.

Comment: cool, thanks you ...does that constraint work in rails 2.3.8?

Comment: @Sean -- when it goes to the path, won't it always do a .where ... but what happens with the redirected page and there is no path?  I have my show action added....thanks!

Comment: Angela, being that you're on 2.3.8, I don't think any of the code that I posted will work.  I will update it according to your version.  Also, you should have a separate controller for your landing page redirects because your landing page should have a different action than the redirect.

Comment: yep super that's awesome, doing the search based on the shortname through the controller works...